# Backbone Layout Manager - Property 'parent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

I've been following the example code shown [here](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Example-usage).

Here I'm simply trying to return a layout manager view.

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'layoutmanager'], 
     function($, _, Backbone, Layout){
        'use strict';

        return Backbone.Layout.extend({
            template: '#main-layout'
        });
});
```

Here, I'm instantiating a new view called myView. It's being loaded using requirejs.

```
require(['app', 'jquery', 'myView'], function (app, $, myView) {
    'use strict';
    var myView = new myView();
    myView.$el.appendTo(".container");
    myView.render();
});
```

Rendering the view causes the following error to pop up in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
```

Comment: It's probably best for your View Class to be capitalized while the View Instance would be lowercase. `var myView = new myView()` overwrites the variable named `myView` with the new instance. That means you can only create one instance of `myView` in this script. If you were to try again, the second time you tried `new myView()` you would be trying to instantiate the first instance of `myView`. In other words, change `function (app, $, myView)` to `function (app, $, MyView)` and `var myView = new myView();` to `var myView = new MyView();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `myView.$el.appendTo(".container");` you should insert the view into a parent view:

```
var myView = new myView();
var container = Layout.getView('.container');
container.insertView(myView);
myView.render();
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful response, I'm still not getting it to work, but I think that is due to my lack of understanding about Layout Manager.

Comment: Now I've finally got some grip on Layout manager, I've found that you have to either insert views into a layout, like what you've put up here, or you have to call the render method on the view.

Comment: Excellent! Btw, if you ask @tbranyen a question on twitter, he'll very often write back.